# A page with input controls when hosted in windows azure is not accessible?

Tags: asp.net, azure

Am trying to host an aspx page which takes input from user(has several textboxes). am able to access all other pages well. when navigated to that page, am getting an exception saying

> The content is blocked due to security reasons.

Please help me out!!

Comment: What is the name of the file and location in your project ? i.e /App_Data ?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in Azure that would block your ASPX page from being accessed due to security reasons. So, this is either the problem of misconfigured `web.config`, wrong page certificate (as long as you are using HTTPS connection) or your browser.

Try to search your `web.config` for similar lines:

```
 <authorization>
   <deny users="?"/>
 </authorization>
```